# Mypy not finding stubs already installed

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy, typing, python-3.10

I'm running Mypy inside a gitlab CI/CD, and mypy can't find installed stubs, even though I've tried to use the --install-types option.

I've also tried creating a virtual env and install all packages, setting up the MYPYPATH and/or PYTHONPATH with the directory where the packages are installed, but I ended up with the same errors.

Here is the output of the CI worker:

```
mypy --install-types --non-interactive backoffice coupons
Requirement already satisfied: types-pytz in ./dev_packages (2022.2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: types-requests in ./dev_packages (2.28.11)
Requirement already satisfied: types-urllib3<1.27 in ./dev_packages (from types-requests) (1.26.25)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2 -> 22.3
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
coupons/models.py:4: error: Library stubs not installed for "pytz" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)
Installing missing stub packages:
/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install types-pytz types-requests
Found 3 errors in 3 files (checked 66 source files)
coupons/models.py:4: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-pytz"
coupons/utils.py:6: error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)
backoffice/accounts.py:8: error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)
backoffice/accounts.py:8: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-requests"
backoffice/accounts.py:8: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
backoffice/accounts.py:8: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
make: *** [.make/lint.mk:57: mypy] Error 1
```

Does anyone faced this issue before and how did you fixed it?

Thanks